# The fprintf() function can't persist the data to the file; must be followed by fflush() function?

Tags: c, io, c++

I am using the `fopen()` function open a file to write, and return a `FILE` pointer. I then use this pointer with `fprintf()`, but data doesn't persist my writes to the file. Is this Direct IO / `O_DIRECT` related, or what is the problem?

Comment: “open” function has the O_DIRECT flag, but "fopen" function doesn't have.

Answer (score 5):

You either need to call [`fflush()`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/fflush.3), or just [`fclose()`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/fclose.3) the file when you're done writing to it. `fclose()` will attempt to flush before closing. This behavior is a part of ISO C and POSIX so you can rely on it. See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_1.13.0/com.ibm.zos.r13.bpxbd00/fclose.htm%23fclose) for more information about `fclose()`:

> Flushes a stream, and then closes the file associated with that
>    stream. Afterwards,
>    the function releases any buffers associated with the stream. To flush means
>    that unwritten buffered data is written to the file, and unread buffered
>    data is discarded.

If you keep writing to a file and never flush or close it, the OS will start flushing data to the file "when it's ready to", after enough writes are queued up.

Comment: Thanks, Will! And I think if I use "open" function and O_DIRECT flag, the data will be written on disk immediately.

Comment: Right, and all caches will be bypassed, which can be a bad thing, and influence read caches as well. You didn't mention what OS you're using, but `O_DIRECT` and `O_SYNC` can be a good solution for Linux, for example (although `O_DIRECT` is often recommended against for reasons above). The safest/most portable option would just be to `fflush()` when you need to. No problem, glad to help!

Comment: *stdio* will starting writing to the file. The buffer is in `stdio`, not the operating system. Once a write gets into the operating system it will get to the file eventually, barring crashes. The issue is the buffering in `stdio`, which nothing flushes except flush or close.

Comment: Note that if you return from `main()` or call the regular `exit()` function, then open file streams will be closed, with pending output flushed to disk (or wherever the output was intended to go).  If you call one of the 'emergency exit' functions (`_exit()`, etc), or if your program crashes (memory faults, etc) this won't happen.